# Как распределить деньги между всеми пользователями в бд?

Tags: php, sql

Мне необходимо узнать кол-во пользователей в базе данных, а потом между ними разделить деньги (поровну). Я сделал так, но выдает **Error: Could not...**:

```
<?php
require_once("config/connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit_button']))
{
    $con = new connect();

    $cash = 1000;


    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM persons";
    $result = mysqli_query($con->Connection(), $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result); // кол-во пользователей в бд 
    //die($rows[0]) выводит 8, все правильно, т.к в базе действительно 8 пользователей

    $sum = $cash/$rows[0]; // разделяю деньги между всеми пользователями в бд
    //die($sum) ничего не выводит, хотя делю число на число

    $sql2 = "UPDATE persons SET money+=('$sum')";
    if (mysqli_query($con->Connection(), $sql2)) {
        die("Records was updated successfully.");
    }else{
        die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($sql2));
    }
}
```

На странице появляется странная ошибка:

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\OSPanel\domains\financial\cash.php on line 20 ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT COUNT(id) FROM persons.
```

20 строка - самая последняя, а текст ошибки вообще связан с 1ым запросом, не понимаю. Помогите

Answer (score 0):

Я исправил запрос и все заработало - `$sql2 = "UPDATE persons SET money = money + ('$sum')";`